# Diiference between three squashed sphere and three sphere and number of susy

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, supersymmetry, superconformality

First I know that three sphere $S^3$ and [squashed sphere](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=squashed+sphere) $S_b^3$
\begin{align}
S_{b}^{3} = \begin{array} & R^2 \times S_{r}, \quad r=b, \quad b\rightarrow 0 \\
R^2 \times S_{r}, \quad r=\frac{1}{b}, \quad \frac{1}{b} \rightarrow 0 \end{array}
\end{align}

First i want to know why many people do some research on squahsed sphere. What is physical importance, effect on squahsed sphere?

It seems to me that squashed sphere is just deformation of sphere, with deformation parameter $b$ which gives some modification on background metric.

And second from superconformal theory, 
$N=2$, $S^3$ theory which has $8$ supercharge, But squashing sphere breaks supersymmetry.

How this kinds of thing happen?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which people?

Comment: @Qmechanic, the relevant material i look for are [1102.4716] and [1109.4734]

Comment: What is your actual and precise question about the things you mention in this question? If you've read sources detailing this, surely they explain "how this kinds of thing happen".

Comment: @ACuriousMind, they just state the number of supercharge breaks. I want to know how this kinds of thing happens

Comment: @ACuriousMind, In the squashed sphere, by introducing R-symmetry wilson line operator which make the number of susy (here 2 supercharge) which is well explained in above references.  I want to know the process before preserving. $i.e$, how squashsed sphere breaks the number of susy.